# Run flutter deploy with entrypoint

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a flutter project which has several entry points (main.dart classes), is there any way how to pass that to the `flutter deploy` command? Something like flutter deploy -t lib/main_test.dart or so.

From the official documentation https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web#before-you-begin (see last point 8) the flutter deploy automatically runs `flutter build web --release`, which in my case should be  `flutter build web -t lib/main_test.dart --release`. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced this issue and resolved it by replacing `"source": "."` with `"public": "build/web"` under `firebase.json` that was generated from `firebase init hosting`. After that, run `Flutter build` command like how you did with `flutter build web -t lib/main_test.dart --release` which generates the the app into the `/build/web` directory. Finally, run `firebase deploy` to deploy.